# Minimum - Tiebreak using a second column

Tags: r

This is probably something very basic, but say I have a data frame like:

```
  name value
1    C   100
2    B    30
3    D    50
4    A    30
```

Code:

```
name <- c("C", "B", "D", "A")
value <- c(100, 30, 50, 30)
frame <-  data.frame(name, value)
```

I can find the row with the minimum value with:

```
fMin <- which.min(frame$value) 
frame[fMin, ]
##   name value
## 2    B    30
```

But what if I want to use a second column in case of a tie?  Say, if there is a tie using `value`, the row with the minimum `name` would be returned:

```
5    a    30
```

Is there a built-in function for that or should I implement my own?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `order` or `interaction` for this:

```
which.min(with(frame, order(value, name)))
which.min(with(frame, interaction(value, name)))
```

Comment: Works like a charm, thanks! BTW, would you use `order` or `interaction` for a real world scenario?